# Why does HDMI cut off randomly for a couple seconds?

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, hdmi

The setup: I've got an NVIDIA GTX 980 Ti run by nvidia-dkms 378.13-5 using modeline `3840x2160 60.00*+ 59.94 50.00 29.97 25.00 23.98` on an up-to-date Arch Linux. This is connected via HDMI to a TV receiver. The TV receiver is connected via S/PDIF to an amplifier and a proprietary cable to a 4K TV.

The symptom: Every so often the HDMI signal is "broken" for about 1-2 seconds: the screen goes black and the sound via the amplifier cuts out.

Some tweaks/data from nvidia-settings:

- Force Composition Pipeline / Force Full Composition Pipeline in nvidia-settings.
- Setting PowerMizer to Adaptive rather than Auto.
- Setting colour space to RGB rather than YCbCr444.
- The GPU temperature never seems to go above 60C.
- While the colour range is set to full the "Current Color Range" still says "Limited". Could it be that the driver keeps trying to change the colour range?

It *just* happened again (twice in a minute, not running any video or fullscreen applications), and there's nothing in `dmesg` or `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

```
$ uname --kernel-name --kernel-release --kernel-version --machine --processor --hardware-platform --operating-system # anonymized 
Linux 4.10.9-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Apr 8 12:39:59 CEST 2017 x86_64 unknown unknown GNU/Linux
```

Reducing the frame rate to 30 Hz seems to fix it (no glitches for about an hour), but that's not exactly to spec.

As a side note, with the latest drivers in Windows 7 I can run 3840x2160 @ 60.00 with maximum colour depth settings and YCbCr444 having no glitches, but sound doesn't get through.

---

I've been in contact with Nvidia, and they have escalated to their Linux team. Will keep this updated.

Comment: Anything written to `dmesg` while that happens?